# VBoxManage Error (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED) while converting to RAW

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, virtualbox, vmdk

I'm trying to convert VMDK obtained from AWS to RAW but VBoxManage fails and throws back to `"VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED"` error!

Is there any solution?

---

Environment:

CentOS 6.5

VBoxManage 4.3.8r92456

---

```
[root@dhcp-xxx-xx-xx-xx Disks]# **VBoxManage clonehd downloadedImage.vmdk foo.img --format RAW**
VBoxManage: error: Could not get the storage format of the medium '/home/swapniku/Documents/Disks/downloadedImage.vmdk' (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80bb0005), component Medium, interface IMedium, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "OpenMedium(Bstr(pszFilenameOrUuid).raw(), enmDevType, enmAccessMode, fForceNewUuidOnOpen, pMedium.asOutParam())" at line 178 of file VBoxManageDisk.cpp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the root cause. VBoxManage fails to identify latest versions of VMDK. So I used `qemu-img` to convert VMDK to RAW. I hope this helps!